# how to create service which gets the information from google places API

Tags: javascript, android, web-services, google-places-api, wikitude

I'm creating an android app which uses AR and camera to find different places around it and highlight them when displayed. [image]

It is developed using wikitude SDK(javascript API). I took reference of wikitude documentation from [this link](https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/7.1/android/browsingpois.html#displaying-native-detail-screen) and built the app till this point. This app displays random POIs but I want POIs as google places. How to a create service which gets information from google places API so that I can then inject that in my application? Which google place API should I use?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you use the [Google Places API - Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details).

**Google Maps API**: Lets you add various types of base maps, draw various overlays on the map and use other services such as Directions.

**Google Places API**: Finds detailed information about places, use your current location and has auto complete features.

Comment: I have doubt that does i need to create service or i can directly used google place API in my application

Comment: I don't understand which API should i used from google?